# Creating google chart from database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses a SQL database to store data. I want to extract two datetime columns from this database, and I want to use these values instead of the hard coded date values in the view below to display the chart for the values stored in the database table.

View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['timeline'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({

            cols: [
                { id: 'Session', label: 'Session', type: 'int' },
                { id: 'start', label: 'Season Start Date', type: 'date' },
                { id: 'end', label: 'Season End Date', type: 'date' }
            ],

            rows: [
                { c: [{ v: 'Baltimore Ravens' }, { v: 'Date(2000, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2001, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New England Patriots' }, { v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers' }, { v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New England Patriots' }, { v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New England Patriots' }, { v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers' }, { v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Indianapolis Colts' }, { v: 'Date(2006, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2007, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New York Giants' }, { v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers' }, { v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New Orleans Saints' }, { v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Green Bay Packers' }, { v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'New York Giants' }, { v: 'Date(2011, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2012, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Baltimore Ravens' }, { v: 'Date(2012, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2013, 1, 5)' }] },
                { c: [{ v: 'Seattle Seahawks' }, { v: 'Date(2013, 8, 5)' }, { v: 'Date(2014, 1, 5)' }] }
            ]
        });

        var options = {
            height: 450,
            timeline: {
                groupByRowLabel: true
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: so you know about injecting values into your View using Razor? That's what you need to do

Comment: Pass a model to your view and then use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` to convert it to a javascript array